# Launch external application from C++ program and attach it to visual 2008 debugger while debugging host in WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, debugging

Basically I have Host and Child program. I do not have sources for Child so I can't change anything in it. I want to launch Host from debugger, which at some point should launch Child program. I want to attach Child automatically for debugging session as well (so any breakpoints set in DLL sources loaded under Child process will hit).

How to do this in Visual Studio 2008 C++ with standard WinAPI?

I tried this:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = {0};

sei.cbSize = sizeof (SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
sei.fMask  = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
sei.lpVerb = "open";
sei.lpFile = "Child.exe";
sei.lpParameters = "/Param";
sei.nShow  = SW_SHOWNORMAL;

if (ShellExecuteEx (&sei))
{
    WaitForSingleObject (sei.hProcess, INFINITE);
}
```

But this does not attach debugger for Child.exe

Comment: Is your debugger attached to `Host.exe`? Can a debugger attach to two processes at once? I rather suspect not, but I could be proved wrong?

Comment: @David - Visual Studio is capable of debugging multiple processes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a404w14b.aspx

Comment: @linux Well I never. Is nothing impossible these days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `gflags.exe` program.  This will be accessable from a VS command prompt.  You can specify a debugger to launch when the child program gets launched.  By specifying `vsjitdebugger.exe` as the debugger in `gflags.exe` you can select the currently running VS instance to be the debugger.

**Edit:**

Sorry about the confusion.  Gflags is NOT default in Visual Studio.  You will need the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551063%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  However if all you want to do is set the default debugger for a specific image you can use [IFEO](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2005/02/21/377663.aspx) which is all `gflags.exe` does anyways :)

Comment: Could you post some more details? I can't find option to select debugger for child program

Comment: Launch gflags and then look for the 'Image File' options, usually a tab. Enter the name of the child process EXE into the 'Image' field.  Hit tab.  Look for the 'Debugger' field.  You can enter 'vsjitdebugger.exe' there.  As soon as the child process is launched, the debugger entered will be launched.