# Unable to debug through a second binary being called from first binary in Visual Studio solution

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, debugging, debug-symbols

I have a solution where I have added two C/C++ projects. The First C++ project calls the second C project's binary to use some of its functionality. While I am trying to debug the first binary, I expect the debug control to switch to the second binary where I have placed relevant breakpoints when the second binary is invoked using the `system` function. But for the code in the second binary, I am getting the error "the breakpoint will not currently be hit no symbols have been loaded" while putting the breakpoint.

The debug switch to the second binary was working previously but has stopped. I have already tried several options suggested to clean and rebuild the solution, checking whether the second binary appears in `Debug->Windows->Modules/Process` and enable/disable e.g `Tools->Debugging->Enable Just My Code` etc but failing to get it to work.

Comment: Is it the case that the debug file .pdb usually is out of date inside your debug directiry?

Comment: `To use the full features of the Visual Studio debugger (like hitting breakpoints) when attaching to a process, the app must exactly match your local source and symbols. `
[Use debugger features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022#use-debugger-features)

Comment: @MarcoBeninca no I have cleaned and deleted the 2nd binary and the .pdb files manually to make sure that the binary and debugger files are latest.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT yes agree with this and hence I have cleaned the debug directory several times to make sure the source and .pdb files are latest and generated fresh

Comment: Make sure the working directory in the project settings match the location of the binary and pdb files

Comment: @MarcoBeninca yes I made sure that working dir during debugging is properly set as part of Configuration Properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  found an extension: [Microsoft Child Process Debugging Power Tool 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool2022&ssr=false#review-details)

And  enable child process debugging in Debug->other debug  targets:
[image]

Then open the file of child process  and add a breakpoint  in the running solution.
It is able to debug console and MFC. No need to attach to process.

Comment: Hi, @Krishna Oza : Did the answer work for you?  Test: A starts B, then attach to process B. It is able to find B's debug symbols and breakpoints. Note: attach to A cannot debug B.

Comment: this worked in a similar way I was expecting the process switch should happen

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do is possible. The simplest solution in my mind would be to have a second instance of Visual Studio up and running, and then attach to the second process once it is created by the first. You should be able to hit your breakpoint that way

Comment: it is possible and was working I just call the second C binary from the first C++ program using `system` function call and have both the projects loaded in visual studio under same solution. i cannot start the second binary since the arguments for the second binary comes from first C++ program sort of like the first C++ program is just kind of wrapper for second C binary

Comment: You don't need to start it. Let the first application start it like it would normally, and then just attach to it (assuming the process is running long enough for you to do that).

As to why it was working before I'm not sure, I was under the impression that running a separate binary with `system` would be treated like a completely external process so I'm surprised it ever worked

Comment: the second process doesn't run long enough else I could have used the attach to process from the same session of visual studio.

Comment: Can you modify the code of the second process so that you add a delay (or perhaps cin ) for testing purposes?

Comment: Now your intent is clearer... maybe this can help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047464/launch-external-application-from-c-program-and-attach-it-to-visual-2008-debugg)